# Lazy initialization, ORMs, and lambdas

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I was searching for a lightweight proxy so that we could lazy instantiate one or many objects in one hit.

rationale: perhaps the requests are batched up and sent to a server.  i.e. that leads to n * latency if it is done individually.  Additionally, if those batched requests could be served by one lambda or SQL statement, there's a potential for an additional time saving.

**Scenario:**
say we have a database, a POCO model, a way of exposing that model (code generation/serialization), and a Silverlight client.  The thought is, wouldn't it be neat if we could describe updates in terms of the POCO model instead of pushing these through CRUD style services?  Like send an object graph instead.

Is this kind of thing covered in WCF?  The only thing is, I'd rather not be using WCF.  Also, something like nhibernate seems best in an ASP scenario.

My first thought was to do something like this, but so far that doesn't get me very far.

```
            private Lazy<Person> _person = new Lazy<Person>(() => new Person());
            public Person person
            {
                get { return _person.Value; }
            }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a proxy... It is simply lazy initialization.

Comment: And overly complex lazy initialisation at that. What is wrong with if (_person.value == null) {
 _person = new person();
}

return _person;

Comment: gee.  So many downvotes.  That's not a good motivation for explaining the full picture.

Comment: question rephrased.  Trying to come up with a scheme for a distributed scenario.  I'd like to have a representation of an ORM on the client.

Comment: This still doesn't feels like a real question. Is there a problem or optimisation you need to add to some existing code? If so introducte the problem a bit clearer and ask a direct question instead of a rationale saying perhaps ....

Comment: I've added a scenario now.  I mean, it's possible to use a RIA/WCF/Web Service, but after comming up with a clean model, it seems a pity to not be able to work with that model indirectly.  This question is a whim along the code first / code once lines (insert other principles here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should create a 'question' list on the client with lazy initialisation that executes the entire 'question' list once a single item has te be loaded. After this you can simply start a new list and load it once needed.

You could even add a little thread to empty the 'question' list on a background thread just to make sure you're using the network efficiently (based on priority or something).

Comment: I was thinking in that direction... some sort of two phased initialization.  Haven't yet come up with a by contract way of doing it though (i.e. client-side contract must match the server side one).

Comment: All the ideas I have are a lot of code to write and would be completely custom solutions. Maybe someone knows a generally accepted way of doing this.

Comment: exactly.  It'd be awesome to solve this in a pure schema centric kind of way.  I don't mind if there's code generation involved... just so long as there's a pattern.